# difference between dates in same group

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, datediff, date-difference

If I take the dates from the Group B, then I have to find the maximum difference between any two consecutive dates from the group B and display that days_difference as a separate column. Also want to display those two dates in two different columns which had maximum days_difference.

Condition: Two class id may have same Class-Name in the data. As you can see Class-ID 1238 and 1252 have same Class-Name. Output should be for every class-id

So result should have: ClassID, ClassName, Date1 , Date 2, DateDiff

```
ClassName | Dates     | ClassID  | Spend($)
ClassA    | 21-Jun-16 | 1238     | 1
ClassA    | 27-Jun-16 | 1238     | 2
ClassA    | 14-Apr-11 | 1252     | 3
ClassA    | 15-Apr-11 | 1252     | 4
ClassC    | 26-Oct-15 | 1261     | 5
ClassC    | 21-Oct-15 | 1261     | 6
ClassA    | 10-Dec-10 | 1252     | 21
ClassC    | 15-Dec-14 | 1261     | 23
ClassC    | 15-May-14 | 1261     | 34
ClassA    | 10-Jan-09 | 1252     | 54
ClassA    | 12-Jun-09 | 1238     | 65
ClassA    | 29-Jun-12 | 1238     | 76
ClassA    | 11-Apr-08 | 1252     | 87
ClassA    | 01-Apr-16 | 1252     | 56
ClassC    | 16-Oct-16 | 1261     | 43
ClassC    | 02-Sep-05 | 1261     | 33
ClassA    | 29-Dec-13 | 1252     | 77
ClassC    | 13-Dec-15 | 1261     | 87
ClassC    | 13-Aug-10 | 1261     | 98
ClassA    | 21-Jan-14 | 1252     | 12
```

Comment: Please show a complete, valid table of expected output, and what you have tried so far.  You talk about "Group", but there is nothing named "Group" in your example.  You mean, "CLassName?"  Please be specific and accurate in posting a question.

Comment: And given that sample input data, what are you expecting the results to look like? Your logic isn't clear to me. I'm guessing that you'll be wanting to take a look at the `LAG()` analytic function, though.

Comment: Output should be for every class-id in the table . For example if you take class-id 1252 then the query should actually traverse all the dates for id-1252 and find the difference between two consecutive dates which have maximum days_difference for id-1252. So same thing for other class-id's in the table too. I am sorry if the question was a bit confusing.

Comment: If the output is only being grouped by CLASSID then how did you plan on including CLASSNAME in the output? Let's take CLASSID = 1238 as an example. What output do you expect for that CLASSID?

Comment: Output should include class-name. So what to group is totally your choice in order to show the output. For ClassID 1238 I need the class-name, Date1,Date2, Days_Difference_between_Date1andDate2. Date 1 and Date 2 are the consecutive dates for ClassID 1238 having maximum days_difference between them. So if there are 500 distinct class-id's in the table , output shoould have 500 rows. I hope this clears the doubt. Note: Class_name is not unique for every class-id. Two id's can have exactly same class-name.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments you can use `lag()` function here and then filter rows with maximum date difference:

```
with t1 as (select classname, classid, 
                   lag(dates) over (partition by classname, classid 
                                        order by dates) dt1, 
                   dates dt2, 
                   dates - lag(dates) over (partition by classname, classid 
                                                order by dates) diff
              from t ),
     t2 as (select classname, classid, dt1, dt2, diff, 
                   max(diff) over (partition by classname, classid) mdiff
              from t1)
select classname, classid, dt1, dt2, diff
  from t2 
  where diff = mdiff
  order by classname, classid
```

---

Test data and output:

```
create table t (classname varchar2(8), dates date, classid number(5), spend number(3));
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2016-06-21', 1238,  1);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2016-06-27', 1238,  2);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2011-04-14', 1252,  3);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2011-04-15', 1252,  4);
insert into t values ('ClassC', date '2015-10-26', 1261,  5);
insert into t values ('ClassC', date '2015-10-21', 1261,  6);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2010-12-10', 1252, 21);
insert into t values ('ClassC', date '2014-12-15', 1261, 23);
insert into t values ('ClassC', date '2014-05-15', 1261, 34);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2009-01-10', 1252, 54);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2009-06-12', 1238, 65);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2012-06-29', 1238, 76);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2008-04-11', 1252, 87);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2016-04-01', 1252, 56);
insert into t values ('ClassC', date '2016-10-16', 1261, 43);
insert into t values ('ClassC', date '2005-09-02', 1261, 33);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2013-12-29', 1252, 77);
insert into t values ('ClassC', date '2015-12-13', 1261, 87);
insert into t values ('ClassC', date '2010-08-13', 1261, 98);
insert into t values ('ClassA', date '2014-01-21', 1252, 12);

CLASSNAME CLASSID DT1         DT2               DIFF
--------- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------
ClassA       1238 2012-06-29  2016-06-21        1453
ClassA       1252 2011-04-15  2013-12-29         989
ClassC       1261 2005-09-02  2010-08-13        1806
```

Comment: Thank you!! But the problem is that there is duplication of the CLASS-ID in in my case. If there are 500 distinct class-id in the table t, I am getting 650 rows in the final result instead of getting 500

Comment: So in your data You have more than one ClassName for the same ClassId. In  your examples we had no such rows. 
I don't know what You want in this situation, but I suspect that You have to remove `classname` in `partition by` clause. 
Depending of all logic - You have to do it everywhere or only in subquery `t2`.